# Spring @Autowired vs bean.xml interfaces implementacion

Tags: java, spring, interface

Hola a todos tengo una duda sobre Inyección de dependencias para interfaces o implementaciones

Tengo una clase  **Impl**

```
public class ImprimeMensajeImpl implements ImprimeMensaje {
@Autowired
private ProveedorMensaje proveedorMensaje = null;
.....etc
System.out.println(proveedorMensaje.getMensaje());
```

Esta es mi otra clase `interface`

```
package com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos;

public interface ProveedorMensaje {

    public String getMensaje();
}
----------------------     mi archivo de configuracion   ---------------------
bean.xml
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="renderer" class="com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ImprimeMensajeImpl">
</bean>
```

Aquí todo funciona según entiendo con la anotación `@Autorrired` en la clase `ImprimeMensajeImpl`  se inyecta ProveedorMensaje   (ojo que es una interface) y si funciona todo bien imprime mensaje

Mi consulta es, si esto quiero traducirlo a `xml` debería ser así

```
bean.xml
<!-- <context:annotation-config />  -->

<bean id="renderer" class="com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ImprimeMensajeImpl">
        <property name="proveedorMensaje" ref="proveedor" />
</bean>
```

esto no funciona no entiendo por que , por que ProveedorMensaje  es una interface ?? pero si con una anotacion si funcina !!!

ahora si declaro el `bean impl`

```
 <!-- <context:annotation-config />  -->

<bean id="renderer" class="com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ImprimeMensajeImpl">
        <property name="proveedorMensaje" ref="proveedor" />
</bean>

<bean
  id="proveedor"
  class="com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ProveedorMensajeIMP " />
```

Acá si funciona  según entiendo con `@Autowired` funciona inyectar una variable `interface` pero en un xml no ?

Answer (score 0):

La primera forma no te funciona porque lo que estás diciendo es: Crea y registra en tu contexto un bean que sea un objeto de la clase `com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ImprimeMensajeImpl` y que su identificador sea `render`. Ah, pero para crearlo inyecta en la propiedad `proveedorMensaje` el bean que tienes que tener registrado en tu contexto cuyo identificador es `proveedor`. Como, al parecer (por el contenido que compartes del archivo bean.xml), este bean no existe en el contexto de Spring, el proceso falla al intentar inyectar la propiedad y por ende crear el bean `renderer`.

**bean.xml**

```
<!-- <context:annotation-config />  -->
<bean id="renderer" class="com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ImprimeMensajeImpl">
    <property name="proveedorMensaje" ref="proveedor" />
</bean>
```

Ahora, la segunda forma si te funciona porque sí estás indicándole a Spring que cree y registre en su contexto el bean cuyo identificador es `proveedor` y que este sea un objeto de la clase `com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ProveedorMensajeIMP`. Por esto no fallará la creación del bean `renderer`.

**bean.xml**

```
<bean id="renderer" class="com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ImprimeMensajeImpl">
    <property name="proveedorMensaje" ref="proveedor" />
</bean>

<bean id="proveedor" class="com.bolsadeideas.ejemplos.ProveedorMensajeIMP " />
```

Con `@Autowired` te funciona porque debes estar utilizando un `autoscan` y Spring encuentra todas las clases anotadas con aquellas anotaciones que indican que debe crear un bean de esa clase y entonces no tiene problemas para realizar las inyecciones.